# emacs gdb source code window focus issue

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am using emacs 25.1 and gdb 7.12 now. but when I run "M-x gdb -i=mi a.out",then set break point and issue next command, a source code window alway popup to get focus, then if I want to issue next command again, I have to switch to the gdb window firstly, otherwise, keyboard input will be direct to the source code file.

We should keep focus on the gdb window rather than switch focus to the source code window.

Am I wrong to use this gdb mode? BTW,gud-gdb mode works fine.[image]

Comment: @Gabor Retvari -- If no one answers in the near future, please consider adding specific Emacs commands that are being called so that anyone who uses Emacs can trace the source code.  As it stands now, people unfamiliar with using this library don't know what Emacs command is being called when a user "want to issue next command again."  In other words, go through the question and edit it to include the exact Emacs commands that are being issued.  Then, any number of forum participants can answer this question even if we don't use the library.

Comment: Minor clarifications: For me the problem arises when not using `gdb-many-windows` mode (i.e., when `gud-gdb` is set to show only the command buffer and the source buffer which I think is the most convenient mode when screen estate is limited) but, unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to systematically trigger it: at some point the focus becomes confused and then a simple `run` or `next` command suddenly appear in the source buffer instead of the command buffer. I set the bounty in the hope that someone knowledgeable has found why this annoying behavior arises and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

**1) They (I know, I know ... who's "They"? :-) have mucked with gdb.**

**2) See #1**

I'm generally a solution type of person, but workaround works in this case, for now.

**a) Use gud-gdb instead of gdb**

**b) To keep the gdb command window from being clobbered, use:**

```
set-window-dedicated-p
```

I use as follows:

```
(defun pgmdb (pgm)
    (gud-gdb (format "gdb -fullname %s" pgm))
    (set-window-dedicated-p nil t)
    )
```

That keeps the former functionality somewhat intact.

Hope this helps.